# Panel Horizontal scroll resets to 0 when datagridview cell size changes

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, panel

I have a datagridview and a panel above it. I scroll the panel when the datagridview is scrolled.
The panel contains equal number of textboxes as that of the number of columns in the datagridview.
My problem is when I resize a datagridview column, I also resize the textbox above it. This works fine but the panel horizontally scrolls to origin.
How can I prevent the panel horizontal scroll to reset to origin?

```
private void dataGridView1_ColumnWidthChanged(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        TextBox txt;
        int x = 40;
        panel1.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(dataGridView1.HorizontalScrollingOffset,0);
        panel1.HorizontalScroll.Value = dataGridView1.HorizontalScrollingOffset;
        IOrderedEnumerable<DataGridViewColumn> coll= from DataGridViewColumn doc in dataGridView1.Columns orderby doc.DisplayIndex select doc;

        foreach (DataGridViewColumn dc in coll)
        {
            if (dc.Visible)
            {
                txt = (TextBox)panel1.Controls["txt" + dc.Name];
                txt.Width = dc.Width - 5;
                txt.Location = new Point(x, dataGridView1.Location.Y - 25);
                x += txt.Width + 5;
            }
        }
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Comment: Is the AutoScroll property of this panel set to 'true'?

Comment: yes.. tried with AutoScroll both true and false.